# (Design Support Library) CollapsingToolbarLayout How to make it scroll always?

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make a CollapsingToolbarLayout scrolling always even if I don't need to scroll on my view.

I have seen something similar in WhatsApp application.

Here is a link to see what I want :

[image]

My code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.Profile">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/tof" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyMaterialTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




<include
    android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/content_profile" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content profile code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_profile" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.example.yasser.version6.Profile">


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: You mean to say that your app functions as intended, but there isn't enough content present in your `NestedScrollView` to trigger a suitable scroll to collapse the toolbar?

Comment: I have a content in the NestedScrollView but not enough to scroll, I just want to scroll the collapsing toolbar down and up

Comment: Ok. Well one (slightly hacky) option is to ensure the size of the content loaded into your `NestedScrollView` (which can be set to `height:wrap_content`) is always large enough to cause a collapsed toolbar (which would be the height of your window less the height of your collapsed toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example:**

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

Use it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                    android:tint="#11000000"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9" />
```