# Android Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-coordinatorlayout

I change my post. I have problem with CoordinatorLayout.I do not quite mastered this concept to create animations.Some help would be welcome.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="#ff7788"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="@string/id"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="@string/taille"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="@string/type"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                android:text="@string/condition"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_box_black" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

I get this 
[image: Image1]

After scroll

[image: Image2]

The blue part is still visible under the toolbar. I want this part continue to scroll unless the tabLayout reach the toolbar ( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: As i see, you want to do that exactly like first `CollapsingToolbarLayout` means after collapsed, it will hide?

Comment: I want after the first CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse, the second one continue scrolling in so that , in the picture 2 , there are only red and green parts the visible

Comment: i answered, please try it and let me know.Also, you may want to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34827861/4409113

Comment: No change. it doesn't work

Comment: when coordinate layout if any of the options menu icon is clicked the toolbar title text is invisible please help me to display title on tool bar alsways fixed.

Comment: can you show your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this flag for second `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

**Take a look:**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html

Hope that helps.